# get stacktrace as string in vbscript

Tags: excel, vbscript, vba

I have to capture stacktrace at the time of error and actual exception. Currently with the below code it's throwing error every time in `Call Err.Raise` line it show be throw like for line `wrapper.getVariable("IRR").value` or `wrapper.getVariable("GT_Price").value`

```vb
On Error Resume Next      
wrapper.getVariable("IRR").value = excel.range("'Cases'!$H$753")     
wrapper.getVariable("GT_Price").value = excel.range("'Cases'!$H$763")     

If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    Dim errorMessage, objHTTP, URL, json
    errorMessage ="Error while executing EVMLite. Error number " & Err.Number & ". " & Err.Description & " " & Err.Source
    Set objHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")    
    URL = "http://10.93.24.223:9005/vpp/logerror"
    objHTTP.Open "POST", URL, False
    objHTTP.SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
    json = "{""jobId"": """& jobId &""", ""uniqueId"": """& uniqueId &""", ""errorCode"": """& errorCode &""", ""errorMessage"": """& errorMessage &"""}"
    objHTTP.send (json)
    On Error Goto 0
    Call Err.Raise(vbObjectError + 10, "EVM Failed to execute", errorMessage)
    'MsgBox objHTTP.ResponseText
End If
```

Comment: What is the expected output? Add code for `wrapper` and `excel` variables init.

Comment: Is it VBScript or VBA?

Comment: it's in VBScript